# How to Change hover into onclick

Tags: php, css

this is a hover menu but I want to change it into onclick menu?

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Users</span></a>
            <ul>
                 <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>All</span></a>
                    <ul>
                       <li><a href='#'><span>All Registered Users</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                 <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Admin</span></a>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: 1. Your code does not explain how your menu is working actually, 2. This is kind of basic knowledge, not hard to find info if you try to...

Comment: i try it but it doesnt work

Comment: sorry sir im just a newbie in programming :(

Comment: If you are a newbie, asking here to solve this easy issues won't help you stop being it: go ahead and try to learn the basics. Start with JavaScript events, play with them.

Comment: oh ty for being a little bit rude sir Godbless :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css would be like

```
li.has-sub ul{
   display: none;
}
li.has-sub:hover ul{
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    float: left;
}
li.has-sub ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

You can remove the display:block for the

```
li.has-sub:hover ul
```

and make it visible on click using jQuery

```
$('li.has-sub').click(function(){
   if(!$(this).next('ul').is(':visible')){
       $(this).next('ul').show();
   }else{
       $(this).next('ul').hide();
   }
});
```